# How to see actual HIVE queries that are running behind YARN applications in Ambari

Tags: hadoop-yarn, ambari

I have some hive jobs executing in YARN, so in Yarn, if I list applications, I see some HIVE application and corresponding Templeton applications. So, in Ambari how do I see the actual HIVE query that those running HIVE applications are executing? Does Ambari provide any option for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this answered, but if you are running on the TEZ engine, you can find the actual hive query used by taking the following steps:

> 1) From the Ambari home page, hover over the 3X3 grid icon in the top
>   right corner, and select "Tez View"
>
> 2) Next, you can either search by application ID or the hive query
>   itself to find your application.
>
> 3) Select your application - the entire hive query should be displayed
>   here, as well as a nice progress and status indicator.